# ng-class to hide the n>0 occurence of an integer/string on my calendar

Tags: angularjs

I would like to hide any duplicate occurences of a date that shows in my calendar. I currently have a calendar widget, that has dates that looks like this...

```
9      {{ EVENT DATA }}
MON    {{ EVENT DATA }}

9      {{ EVENT DATA }}
MON    {{ EVENT DATA }}

9      {{ EVENT DATA }}
MON    {{ EVENT DATA }}

10     {{ EVENT DATA }}
TUE    {{ EVENT DATA }}

11     {{ EVENT DATA }}
WED    {{ EVENT DATA }}

12     {{ EVENT DATA }}
THURS  {{ EVENT DATA }}
```

I would like it to look like this

```
9      {{ EVENT DATA }}
MON    {{ EVENT DATA }}

       {{ EVENT DATA }}
       {{ EVENT DATA }}

       {{ EVENT DATA }}
       {{ EVENT DATA }}

10     {{ EVENT DATA }}
TUE    {{ EVENT DATA }}

11     {{ EVENT DATA }}
WED    {{ EVENT DATA }}

12     {{ EVENT DATA }}
THURS  {{ EVENT DATA }}
```

Where the n+1 occurence of a date is hidden. I am familiar with using `!$first`, but I would like to figure out how to do `!$first of matching str`.  Anyone have any experience?

Here is a jsfiddle I am playing with. any help is mega appreciated!
[jsfiddle attempt with ng-class](http://jsfiddle.net/m7219uqv/7/)

Comment: One suggestion is do a sort then loop through and add a first occurrence property to each meeting as day increases from prior one

Comment: Use code, in your controller, to group your meetings by day (or just extract the distinct days, since you don't seem to use any information other than the days). Then display the days. In short, it's a job for the controller, not for the view.

Comment: @JBNizet I think you misunderstood. I have added additional info to bridge that gap.

Comment: I haven't misunderstood. If you use code to group meetings by day, you will end up with an array od days, where each day contains an array of meetings, and you'll just need to nested ng-repeat in the view to display the days, and the meetings inside each day.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I will give that a try.

Comment: @IWI I updated my answer according to the new idea you explained to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do an [AngularJS filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) which marks the first items in the collection of repeated ones and then use it in your `ng-repeat`.

The idea is to iterate over the collection and the first time an item is found set a property on it (`isFirst`) as true, and show the day only if that condition exist. Like this:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(collection, key) {
    var output = [],
      keys = [];

    angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      var ikey = item[key];
      if (keys.indexOf(ikey) === -1) {
        keys.push(ikey);
        item['isFirst'] = true;
      }
      output.push(item);
    });

    console.log(output);
    return output;
  };
});
```

Then in your `ng-repeat`...

```
<div class="row individualMeetingRow" ng-repeat="meeting in user.meeting | myFilter:'start_time' | orderBy:['start_time']">

<!-- code omitted for brevity -->
  <!-- HERE -->
  <div class="col-sm-6" ng-show=meeting.isFirst> 
    <p>{{ meeting.start_time | date : "d"}}</p>
    <p>{{ meeting.start_time | date : "EEE"}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right"> 
    <p>{{ meeting.title}}</p>
    <p>{{ meeting.address_country}}</p>
  </div>
```

Where `myFilter` is the name of the just-created filter and `'start_time'` is the criteria you use in order to match the items (and see which one is repeated).

See [**full example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/lealceldeiro/6yue21uc/7/).

Comment: That is a good idea. But I should have mentioned that there are many "meetings per day" in a column that's not in the code. And I need to show those. So I just want to hide the number

Comment: @IWI, But... how would be the expected output. I only see in the question image a blank space between `9 MON` and `10 TUE`. What is suppose to be there? and how are you planning to use those hidden elements?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hiding based on first duplicate start time you can group element on the basis of start time and loop and iterate them in angularjs.

eg. for your meeting array your convert your array as like below:

```
var oldStartTime = 0;
var mainMeetingList= [];
var oldObj = {
    startTime: "",
    meetings: []
};
meeting.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    if(oldStartTime != obj.start_time) {
        oldObj =  {
    start_time: obj.start_time,
    meetings: [obj]
};

oldStartTime = obj.start_time;
mainMeetingList.push(oldObj);
    } else {
    oldObj.meetings.push(obj);
}

});
```

Now you can iterate mainMeetingList array based on start_time and show all meetings for that start time.

```
<div class="row individualMeetingRow" ng-repeat="meetingObj in mainMeetingList orderBy:['start_time']">
  <div class="col-2"> 
    <p>{{ meetingObj .start_time | date : "d"}}</p>
    <p ng-repeat="mt in meetingObj.meetings orderBy:['start_time']">{{ mt.start_time | date : "EEE"}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also $first will match to only first element of array. what if there is 2 meeting on 10th. Then it will not match with first because it is duplicate for 4th element. this can be repeated onward. So I think you should not use first.
I have found $first description on angularjs site is as below:

$first  boolean true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.